# Obtener valores únicos entre dos columnas en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Necesito mantener valores únicos considerando dos columnas, ejemplo

Considerando la tabla:

I  [Fecha]        [Hora_1]    [Hora_2]:

17  2021-08-18     07:01:02    10:16:48:

18  2021-08-18     07:01:02    15:41:25:

19  2021-08-18     13:26:19    10:16:48:

20  2021-08-18     13:26:19    15:41:25

obtener:

I   [Fecha]        [Hora_1]    [Hora_2]:

17  2021-08-18     07:01:02    10:16:48:

20  2021-08-18     13:26:19    15:41:25:

utilizando "drop_duplicates()" no he logrado generarla

Comment: Por algo existe el método `unique`

Comment: @Christian he usado en np.unique pero no logro generar lo que necesito

Comment: no dije que usaras numpy, usa `pd.unique`. Pensé que era algo fácil, ahora no tengo tiempo para elaborar una respuesta pero puedes leer la [documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) y guiarte

Answer (score 0):

Para considerar solo algunas de las columnas puedes utilizar el parametro `subset`. Por ejemplo:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Columna 1', 'Columna2'])
```

Comment: ya probé esa linea, pero no me sirve ya que elimina los valores cuando hay filas repetidas tanto para columa1 como columna2

lo que necesito es obtener los valores únicos entre columna1 y columna2

Comment: Entonces creo que no comprendo exactamente lo que intentas hacer. La linea anterior va a eliminar las filas cuando se tengan duplicados de ambas columnas simultáneamente, es decir, que sean iguales tanto en la primera como en la segunda columna. Si lo que quieres es eliminar las filas que se repitan ya sea en la columna 1 o 2, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es aplicar la función dos veces: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Columna 1']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Columna2'])`. Nota también que puedes especificar qué valor mantener con el parámetro `keep`